# Tensorflow crashes during training, what should I do?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04

When training the model, tensorflow crashes and does not work, although when:

`model.fit(X, y,batch_size=5,epochs=25, validation_split=0.3,callbacks=[tensorboard])`

```
2023-06-14 12:53:37.515906: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-06-14 12:53:37.516050: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-06-14 12:53:37.516128: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-06-14 12:53:38.588014: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-06-14 12:53:38.588102: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-06-14 12:53:38.588112: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1722] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU id 0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2023-06-14 12:53:38.588161: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2023-06-14 12:53:38.588209: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1635] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5463 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0, compute capability: 7.5
Epoch 1/25
```

and crash

reinstall tensorflow and cuda

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

print("devices: ", [d.name for d in device_lib.list_local_devices()])
print("GPUs:    ", tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print("TF v.:   ", tf.__version__)
```

devices:  ['/device:CPU:0', '/device:GPU:0']
GPUs:     [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
TF v.:    2.12.0

WSL 2, Ubuntu 22.04

`nvidia-smi`

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.43.02              Driver Version: 535.98       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 ...    On  | 00000000:06:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 55%   45C    P8              15W / 184W |   7645MiB /  8192MiB |      6%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        23      G   /Xwayland                                 N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A       894      C   /python3.9                                N/A      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It seems related to this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76528720/how-to-use-tensorflow-with-nvidia-quadro-k1200-gpu-on-windows-10)